# JavaFX: Have TilePane use full window width when switching scenes

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to have a `TilePane` spanning the full window width. When setting up my `Stage`, `Scene`, and `TilePane` window without any specific settings, this works as expected. This even is the case when I set `tilePane.setPrefColumns(100)` even though my screen is only wide enough for 9 tiles. I did not set any size for the stage manually.

When my application starts, the scene is first set to width 1, then 320, then 1920 (when started on a 1920x1080 screen). I am running XMonad (a tiling window manager), which might cause the width of 320 in between before showing the window fullscreen.

However, after switching to another scene (`stage.setScene`) and switching back again - re-using the old scene or constructing a new scene using the same code which was used initially - the preferred width of the `TilePane` (way more than 1920) is used to set the width of the scene and stage. As such, the `100` columns mentioned above are "shown", although the screen only is wide enough for 9 columns.

When manually resizing the window, everything "snaps" back to expected values (i.e. 1920 in my case).

How can I make sure that a scene which is (re-)attached to a stage is rendered with the screen's width? How can I trigger a fake "window resized" event? How can I make the scene/pane widths dependent on the stage width instead of the other way around?

I'd prefer solutions which also work in multi-screen setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped in my case, was to assign initial `width` and `height` values to the stage:

```
stage.setWidth(800);
stage.setHeight(600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the scenes are on the same stage what you can do is

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

stage.sceneProperty().addListener(e -> {        
    if(stage.getScene() == EnterSceneYouWantHere)
    {
        tilePane.setMaxWidth(gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth());                                                                                                                                 
        tilePane.setMaxHeight(gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
        tilePane.setMinWidth(gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth());                                                                                                                                 
        tilePane.setMinHeight(gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
    }
});
```

Should work but haven't tested indeed if it does it should work for multiple monitors.

Comment: `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();` throws an `HeadlessException`, even after `stage.show()` (without changing scenes).

Comment: That should have worked properly, I've used that particular line of code before. Try this `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` and replace `gd` with `screenSize`.